# What units is timeout in Rails database.yml?

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In database.yml, is the timeout in seconds or milliseconds? And what specifically is it, the timeout for the entire database connection including wait time for a connection or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the timeout is in milliseconds. This is the entire time which rails app wait for database response. Good practice is to add reconnect option in this file then the application will try reconnecting to the server before giving up in case of a lost connection.

Comment: You can found it for example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Exactly:
"ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds. The max pool size is currently 5; consider increasing it:"

Above that text is an example of database.yml file.

Comment: it's millisecond after you exceed it you'll get error `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)`

Comment: connect_timeout and wait_timeout are two different things

Comment: According to https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html this is incorrect

Answer (score 9):

Number of seconds to block and wait for a connection before giving up and raising a timeout error (default 5 seconds).

```
wait_timeout: 900 # 15 minutes.
timeout: 5000 # 5 seconds.
```

MYSQL Docs say :

```
 1. wait_timeout : The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a
   noninteractive connection before closing it. The default value is 28800.

 2. connect_timeout : The number of seconds that the mysqld server waits for
   a connect packet before responding with Bad handshake. The default value is 10 seconds.
```

**connect_timeout** mysql is mapped to **timeout** defined in **data_base.yml** rails which is set to 5 seconds default.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `checkout_timeout`, the unit is in seconds.

Comment: It might not be seconds (anymore)(?) it might be milliseconds